# C - fprintf() & printf() deleting array element memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, file-io, printf

I fairly new to C Programming, but `fprintf()` & `printf()` is behaving strangely and I'm so confused on why--I need some help understanding and diagnosing this issue.

---

### `fprintf()` Deleting Element of Array

First off, I'm passing in a populated malloc allocated four element char** array into a simple function that will write to a file, everything in the array appears normal and all four elements contain the correct data. The function call in main() looks like this. My array in question is **header**.

**Note**: *I had to cast this normal `(char** array)` as a constant in this function parameter, due to the function header parameter. Our professor gave us the header file and we cannot change anything in them.*

```
pgmWrite((const char**) header, (const int**) matrix, 
    rowPixels, colPixels, outFile);
```

Next, stopping debugger just before it executes the fprintf() & printf() functions, screenshot showing the array is still populated with my 4 elements.

[`pgmWrite()` - Showing array is still fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHrSd.png)

Observe the 4th element of the array after execution of fprintf().

[After `fprintf()` executes, element 3 memory is wiped out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gjaC.png)

When run, `printf()` executes the printing of the array exactly what is shown in the debugger, ending at the 3rd element. Often printing nothing in that spot or in rare cases garbage characters. The behavior of `printf()` is exactly the same as how `fprintf()` is working as well.

---

I'm at a loss here guys, please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. I can only provide these two screenshots, based on me being a new member. I'll try to provide as much information as possible. Thank you. Here is a simplified version of my program. Keep in mind, the professor gave us the function declarations and told us we cannot change them. So, I have to work with what I have here. Also, since this is fileIO, you need to find a *.pgm file to test this.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define rowsInHeader 4
#define maxSizeHeadRow 200

int ** pgmRead( char **header, int *numRows, int *numCols, FILE *in  ){
// INITIALIZING
char *headArr[rowsInHeader][maxSizeHeadRow];
char buffer[100];
int r = 0;
fpos_t pos;
// CREATE: Header
while (r < 4){
// IF: Row in pgm file header lists the dimensions of matrix
if (r == 2){
// CURSOR: Saving pointer location in file (see notes in header for method reference)
fgetpos(in, &pos);
// ASSIGN: Dereference column and row pointers from file
fscanf(in, "%d %d", numCols, numRows);
// CURSOR: Moving back to saved pointer location (see notes in header for method reference)
fsetpos(in, &pos);
}
// ASSIGN: Copying header row into array
fgets(buffer, maxSizeHeadRow, in);
strcpy((char*)headArr[r], buffer);
// POINTER: Reference pointer to headArr[]
header[r] = (char*)headArr[r];
// TRAVERSE: To next row in file
r++;
}
// NOTE: Placeholder for return type
return 0;
}

int pgmWrite( const char **header, const int **pixels, int numRows, int numCols, FILE *out ){
// INITIALIZING
int i = 0;
// WRITE: Header
for (i = 0; i < rowsInHeader; i++){
    fprintf(out, "%s", header[i]);
    printf("%s", header[i]);
}
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
char **header = (char**)malloc(rowsInHeader * sizeof(char));
FILE *inFile = fopen("smallFile.pgm", "r");
FILE *outFile = fopen("TestPicture.ascii.pgm", "w");;
int rowPixels = 0;
int colPixels = 0;
int **matrix = NULL;
// READ & WRITE
matrix = pgmRead(header, &rowPixels, &colPixels, inFile);
pgmWrite((const char**)header, (const int**)matrix, rowPixels, colPixels, outFile);
// FINALIZING
fclose(inFile);
free(header);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never say that, if it was so don't you think c programmers would know?

Comment: needing to cast between pointer types is usually a sign of (design/implementation) errors.

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean? If I said something wrong, I'll be glad to edit my mistake. Can you be more specific on what you mean by, "never say that"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  When you problems with getting code to work, we must see the code.  We do **not** want to see images of your code — we want code that we can copy and edit and study.  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) — and provide us with an MCVE that demonstrates your problem.  It is also important that we know what the input data is and what the result is (and what the result should be).  The problem is not in the code you show in the images.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to segment my code so that others can copy this if need be. Give me a few minutes to fix this up.

Comment: There's no way to debug this without seeing the code. We can't even tell what `i` or `rowsInHeader` is, so we can't tell what the `printf`/`fprintf` statements are doing.

Comment: Show how you create and pass the array in question. Needing the cast is very suspicious.

Comment: I'm sorry for the vagueness guys, I'm brand new to posting code on websites. I just provided a simplified version of my code. You need to download a *.pgm file in order to test this out. Let me know what else I can do.

Comment: What, in your view, is a `.pgm` file and where can such files be downloaded from?  The first line in your main program code: `char **header = (char**)malloc(rowsInHeader * sizeof(char));` is only allocating enough space for single characters, but you need it to allocate that many character pointers.  That's a starting problem – it might be sufficient to account for all the trouble, though there's usually more than one problem when there's a problem like that.  (Bugs cluster together…)

Comment: Another problem is in `pgmRead()`: you define `char *headArr[rowsInHeader][maxSizeHeadRow];` but you probably wanted a 2D array of characters, not of pointers. Fixing this means the casts are not needed. And then you have `header[r] = (char *)headArr[r];` so you are assigning pointers to a function's local variable into the data passed back to `main()`.  That gives you endless trouble because once the function returns, the `headArr` is reused for other purposes; that's why things change when you call `printf()`.  You're abusing data space that doesn't belong to your function any more.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Thank you, I'll adjust those suggestions. In the meantime, here is a link to *.pgm file explanations. I guess pgm stands for portable grey map. The files I'm working with are considered "P2" mode, meaning they're in ASCII format. This allows you to open in a text editor the matrix of pixels and you can adjust the intensity of the grey value. http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/pgma/pgma.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not allocating your array correctly. This line:

```
char **header = (char**)malloc(rowsInHeader * sizeof(char));
```

makes `header` point to an uninitialized region of memory , size `4` bytes.

Then inside your PGM function you write:

```
header[r] = (char*)headArr[r];
```

The code `header[r]` means to access the `r`'th pointer stored in the space pointed to by `headArr`. But since that space is only 4 bytes big, you're actually writing off into the wild blue yonder.

Also, `(char *)headArr[r]` is a mistake. If you did not use the cast, your compiler would have warned you about this mistake.  You should avoid using casts in your code, *especially* using them to make warnings go away. You're saying to the compiler "Ssh, I know what I'm doing" when in fact you don't know what you are doing.

The entire approach with `headArr` is flawed from the start: even if you had actually written the right code to implement what you were trying, you'd be returning pointers into space which is deallocated when the function returns.

Basically the whole `pgmRead` function is a complete mess and it'd be easier to start from scratch. But this time, think carefully about when and where you are allocating memory, and what the types are of your expressions, and *don't use casts*. Let the `pgmRead` function do all the allocation.

(Unfortunately, based on your description it looks like you will have to use your casts to call the `pgmWrite` function since that has a mistake in its signature. `const int **` should be `const int * const *`, and similarly for `const char **`. I'd recommend to actually change `pgmWrite`'s signature accordingly, get your program working, and then once everything is good, then go back to the broken version that you are forced to use.)

Reading [C FAQ - arrays and pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/) might be useful too.

Comment: Thank you, for this informative info @M.M. While I try to implement your edits into my program, could you if you have time, post a reply to what _you_ would do in pgmRead?

I get what you are saying about the memory stack wiping clean after the return. I just can't for the life of me figure out how to assign an outside double pointer to a 2D array. This is our first assignment in class and also my first program in C. Still getting used to the whole pointer thing. (By the way; assignment was due last night, but I'm still determined to understand this and get this program to work right.)

Comment: @MatthewDonaldson I think `header` is supposed to be a 1-D array. The spec doesn't mention anything about multiple header rows, and the function signature you've been provided is correct for returning a 1-D array by reference. (The return value of `pgmRead` is already in use for returning the data, so `header` is "returned" by using a pointer parameter).  So inside the `pgmRead` function you could start with `char *ptr = malloc(numberofbytesfortheheader);`, then read the header into that space, and then "return" it by doing `*header = ptr;` at the end.

Comment: An issue is what exactly you are going to put in that malloc'd space. It's not clear from what you posted whether you are just supposed to return the exact bytes that are in the file, or whether you're supposed to read the header and convert it into a more usable format (e.g. extract the width, height, and maxgrey as integers).  If the former (which would be annoying), then you'd have to read the file into a temporary buffer until you actually know where the end of the header is, since the header is not a fixed number of bytes.